# Azure DevOps notification

Tags: azure-devops, notifications

I have created a notification on Azure to send an email when a card has a field filled as yes and when it is moved to a particular state. The email sends when the card is moved to our Awaiting Tech state but it does not mention the field being filled as yes. I dont understand why this wont work if anybody can help please do!

Comment: Maybe add some details like the notification configuration, an example of the email, and maybe the work item history view?  It's really not enough information to reproduce currently.  If I had to just make a guess, they aren't happening as atomic transactions.  You only get "changed" fields in work item updates.  So it is probably "Yes" on creation, then gets the state moved, which triggers the notification conditions.

Comment: The notification goes as follows
State Changes to 'Awaiting Tech Approval' and 'Late Approval' = Yes  
then send the email and notify that a late approval request is awaiting tech approval. The email is being sent but the email only notifies of the Awaiting Tech State and not about the Late Approval field